# Is there a way to change the number of iterations on the fly in r?

Tags: r, iteration

Say for example, during the execution of a function inside the loop the computed value resulted from the previous iteration signals that a reduce of number of overall iterations is possible. My goal is to be able to reduce the number of total iterations on the fly.

So for example, `for (i in 1:max) { do computation here and figured out that max can be reduced after the third iteration and hence reduce max}`

Comment: This is too vague. Give example code to describe the specifics.

Comment: You can test for a criterion and skip to the `next` iteration repeatedly or use `break`. Read `?"for"`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer that comes to mind is not to use a for loop.

```
i <- 1
MAX <- 100
while (i <= MAX){
  # do stuff
  if (condition) MAX <- 50
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Depending on the nature of your problem there may be more elegant approaches, but this is a direct translation of what you asked for.